# Core Data: incompatible data models for automigration in iOS5 (but okay on iOS4)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5, ios4, core-data-migration

I've got a core data model in an iOS app that's is set up for automigration (using MagicalRecord), has used model versioning nearly from the beginning, and has been working fine with model versioning on iOS 4.2-3.

I recently made a set of changes to the model (pre-production) that yielded the error:

```
Error: The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store
```

I couldn't see any reason why the data model would be incompatible, since I did everything right (add model version, make the change to the new model, set the current model version, run the app). I even double-checked my work and my change logs.  Everything should've been clean.  And indeed, it was fine on my iPad running iOS4.3  However, on an iOS 5 device, the app had no data.

Since this was a pre-production release, I didn't have any qualms about requiring a delete/reinstall to update.  However, I'm now in post-production, and that is unacceptable for this app.

I've now needed to make a small change, adding a string attribute to one of the entities.  Again, it works fine on iOS 4.3, but I get the same incompatible model error on iOS5.  Am I missing something? Is this a documented bug? Have automatic versioning/migrations stopped being supported in iOS5? What can I do to fix this?